# Want to push data to an array, but the new data replaces the old data

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, dom-events

When I want to push data to the `localStorage` array, the new data replaces the old data. How can I fix it?

```js
function addNametext(e) {

    const arrData = inpot1.value

    let text1;
    if (localStorage.getItem("text1") === null) {

        text1 = [];

    } else {

        text1 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("text1"));

    }
    text1.push(arrData);

    localStorage.setItem("name", JSON.stringify(text1));

    alert("SAVED");

    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: LocalStorage stores key/value pairs. Each key can hold one string value, so if you constantly override the same key, you also constantly override the value.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I need to make one key it holds the array value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the key with name `name` but fetching with `text1`. You need to correct that

```
text1 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("text1")); //Notice the key

localStorage.setItem("name", JSON.stringify(text1)); //Notice the key here
```

Comment: @ZaherMohamedMasloub glad to help. Here's a working code https://jsfiddle.net/wickedrahul/c3fsdqnk/